# I've got 10 Errors, 12 Warnings on my site with w3c Validator

Tags: html, doctype, w3c-validation

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fthenozzle.net%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2

Theres my W3C validation. Is it bad that I've got 12 error and 10 warnings? Is this normal?
If so, what am I doing wrong with the Doctype?

I'm using mordernizr.js v2. My fear is that it isn't working and causing validation errors with my doctype. But I'm not sure what the errors mean. Do they mean my site is BROKEN? Or are these so called 'errors' really just warnings.

Here's my site:

http://thenozzle.net/login

username: admin1
pass: admin1

Thanks in advance!
~ Jackson

Comment: You should try to focus your question around what W3C validation means, or why doctype is important. As it is, your question risks being closed as a "code dump. solve my problem" question.

Comment: My question is, is it okay for these errors to be here? Don't see why you voted me down, it's a legitimate question.

Comment: @Jackson - I didn't vote you down, someone else must have thought the same. Yes, your question is legitimate, but this site is unlike a forum in that it aims to create a repository of Q/A for others to browse too, instead of being a personal helpline. So I'm merely suggesting for you to rephrase your question to focus on the *programming problem*, rather than your website.

Comment: @jackson, errors don't really matter, as long as you cross browser test your pages in all the target browsers and it looks fine.

Comment: Thank you, I wish you would've made it an answer so I could mark it correct! Also, are there certain things that can't go in rel tags. The validator says my  value 'category tag' is incorrect.

Comment: I don't really understand the voting down. :/
Yer hurtin' my reputation here.
It seems like this question would be valuable to anyone looking to learn more about w3c validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @petah for the answer...

@jackson, errors don't really matter, as long as you cross browser test your pages in all the target browsers and it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://thenozzle.net/oops"
</script>
```

Outside of your `head`

**Remember, the validator is not logged in.**

Comment: @Jackson, well go through them 1 by 1 and fix them. The latest one I have seen is that the `alt` attribute is not allowed on `div` elements. Pretty obvious fix.

Comment: There were a lot of alt tags on links and divs by mistake, lol. Also I was specifying 'px' in html width property like it was css.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html Since you're using the W3 validator those are recommended by W3.